# Iterate over few digital certificates with subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to write a Python script which will use openssl command to output contents of few digital certificates. The problem is that I am not able to loop through the files with the subprocess.check_output([]) function. Here's what I have got so far:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess  
import os  
import glob  

    for f in glob.glob("*.cer"):
        OUT_PUT = subprocess.check_output(['openssl','x509','-in','f','-noout','-text'])
    print(type(OUT_PUT))
    print(OUT_PUT.decode('utf-8'))
```

I get a feeling that something's wrong with the way I am placing the "f" variable in the function. The above code does not work.
Please advise.

Comment: what do u mean when u say it does not work? Please put the error message u r getting.

Comment: drop the quotes around `f`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be your problem, but as it stands, you have `f` in quotes, so you're just passing through a string (`"f"`) rather than the name of the file you wish to pass to openssl.